# Finding the angle which is located in most intervals of angles

Tags: c++, algorithm, implementation, intervals, angle

I've got angle intervals (in radians) [0,2π)

- for example intervals [(2π)/3,(3π)/4],[π/2,π] etc.
- but there may also be interval [(3π)/2,π/3]

I have to find the angle which is located in most intervals.
What's the best way to find it in C++? 
How can I represent the angle intervals?

Comment: Do all intervals represent counterclockwise movement? What does the interval (3π/2,π/3) represent?

Comment: Yes it represents counterclockwhise movement. Interval [(3π)/2,π/3] which is in degrees [270*,60*]. *-degree

Comment: Two more questions. Are the intervals to be considered open, closed, or half-open? (If they are closed, there are definition problems where intervals touch.) For the second question, note that in general there will be a range of angles (or perhaps several, non-overlapping ranges) that are are "located in the most intervals". Do you want one angle arbitrarily selected from those, or do you want the range(s) representing maximum overlap?

Comment: Then when intervals abut (for example, [0, π/3] and [π/3, π]), the angle π/3 is in two intervals?

Comment: Yes and if you have just those two intervals which you have written then π/3 is the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it by maintaining a partition of [0, 2π] into ranges corresponding to interval coverage, with a count for each range. First, here's how the algorithm would work under the condition that none of the intervals crosses 0 (or 2π). The intervals are also assumed to be normalized as follows: if an interval ends at 0, it is changed to end at 2π; if it starts at 2π, it is changed to start at 0.

1. create a list of (range, count) pairs, initialized with a single range [0, 2π] and a count of 0. (The list will be ordered by the start of the range. The ranges in the list will only overlap at their endpoints and will always cover [0, 2π]).
2. process each interval as described below
3. scan the list for a (range, count) pair with the highest count. Resolve ties arbitrarily. Return an arbitrary angle within the range.

To process an interval `i`:

1. Find the first (range, count) pair (call it `s`) for which `i.start >= s.range.start` (i.e., the range contains `i.start`). (Note that if `i.start` is the end of one range, then it will be the start of another; this pick the pair for which it is the start.)
2. Find the last (range, count) pair `e` for which `i.end <= e.range.end`. (Note that if `i.end` is the start of one range, then it will be the end of another; this picks the pair for which it is the end.)
3. If `i.start > s.range.start` (`i.range` starts in the interior of `s`), split `s` into two (range, count) pairs `s1 = ([s.range.start, i.start], s.count)` and `s2 = ([i.start, s.range.end], s.count)`. Replace `s` in the list with `s1` and `s2` (in that order).
4. If `i.end < e.range.end`, replace `e` in a manner parallel to the previous step, using `i.end` to do the split.
5. For each pair from `s` (or `s2` if `s` was split in step 3) up to and including `e` (or `e1` if `e` was split in step 4), add 1 to the count.

If you don't care to keep track of the actual number of intervals that contain a particular angle, just that it's the maximum, the bookkeeping for intervals that cross 0 (or 2π) is easier: just take the complement of the interval (reverse the start and end) and subtract one from the counts in step 5 instead of adding. If you do need the absolute counts, then do the complement trick and then add 1 to every count on the list.

The above will not deal correctly with intervals that abut (e.g.: [0, π/3] and [π/3, π]; or [2π/3, 2π] and [0, 1]). In those cases, as I understand it, the angle at which they abut (π/3 or 0) should be counted as being in two intervals. The above algorithm could be tweaked so that when an interval start coincides with a range end point, a new (range, count) pair is inserted after the pair in question; the new pair would have a single-angle range (that is, `range.start == range.end`). A similar procedure would apply for the range that starts at the end of an interval. I think that with those tweaks the above algorithm correctly handles all cases.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement a simple [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) to solve this problem.

For each interval, add the start and end of the interval to a vector; sort this vector, then iterate through it. If you have any intervals that cross the 2π-boundary, simply split it into two intervals, which are both inside of (0, 2π).

As you iterate through the list, keep track of how many overlapping itervals there are at the current point, and what the best angle you've seen so far has been (and how many intervals were overlapping at that angle). Once you reach the end, you know what the optimum angle is.

If you need more than one angle, you can rather easily adapt this approach to remember intervals with maximal overlap, rather than single angles.

Comment: If intervals are closed, there's an interesting edge case at angle 0 (which is also 2π). Splitting intervals that cross the boundary compounds the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would involve a list of pairs of start of the interval and how many intervals overlap it:

```
     1        2       3       2              1
|---------|--------|-----|---------------|------|

|------------------|
          |--------------|
                   |---------------------|
                   |----------------------------|
```

So, sort all the start and end points and traverse the list assigning each new interval the count of intervals it overlaps with (increasing it if it's a start point, decreasing otherwise). Then take the maximum from the overlap counts.

Comment: I don't see how this determines which points in the interval you're testing overlap.  In general it may be a single point, part or all of the interval, or even multiple subintervals.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll run into weird edge cases if you don't do this symbolically.

Your angular ranges are not only not exactly representable as binary fractions (introducing rounding errors) they're irrational.  (`Pi` is greater than 3.14159265359 but less than 3.14159265360; how do you say that an angle equals `Pi`/2 besides symbolically?)

The most robust way I see to do it is to take all combinations of intervals in turn, determine their intersection, and see which of these combined intervals are the result of the intersection of the most individual intervals.

This also has a bonus of giving you not just one, but *all* of the angles that satisfy your condition.